# Direct Connection to Oracle DB from Windows Mobile App

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6

I am developing a windows mobile app (.NET compact framework) and I want to insert/update/delete directly to an oracle DB on the server.

is there anyway to do this without a web service ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Oracle, they offer a native Windows CE, Windows Mobile 6 client:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-lite/downloads/10gwin-mobile-096526.html

See the instalation doc at https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E22663_01/doc.11100/e22681/instsqlite.htm#CACBAJAA

ADO.Net
JDBC
ODBC

Comment: That's not exactly what I am looking for.. as I understood from the links this is a standalone software that can manage oracle db on the server. I am looking for a solution I can use from inside my vb.net code of the windows mobile application( like .dll or something )

Comment: What so you think is ado.net or odbc? These are interfaces to access the oracle db

Comment: I use them on desktop application but do they work on .net compact framework (windows mobile applications) ?

Comment: Looks like Oracle supports client DB sync bu no direct DB connection: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12095_01/doc.10303/e12090/nvwcetu.htm

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.
We are using a driver from devart:

https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/

No problems the last years - works like a charme and not that expensive.

HTH
Ruediger

Comment: can I use it to manage the oracle db on server from inside my vb or c# code on .net compact framework ?